# Question about making a high score table in a word guessing game

Tags: c, function, file, if-statement

It is my first few times to practice c programme project and I am trying to finish a word guessing game with a high score table. Although it can run the part of word guessing game smoothly, I cannot fix the part of the high score table at the moment, due to the unknown reasons.

Here is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

const int true = 1;
const int false = 0;


struct highscore {
    char name[20];
    int numofwords;
};


int readwordlist(char wordlist[][20])
{
    FILE* fp;
    int i;
    char word[20];
    
    fp = fopen("wordlist.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Please check your file before starting the game.");
        return false;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 848; i++) {
        fscanf(fp, "%s", word);
        strcpy(wordlist[i], word);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return true;
}


void printshuffleword(char word[])
{
    char wordcopy[20];
    int letternum;
    int index;

    strcpy(wordcopy, word);

    letternum = 0;
    while (letternum < strlen(word)) {
        // Pick a letter randomly
        index = rand() % strlen(word);

        if (wordcopy[index] != '\0') {
            printf("%c", wordcopy[index]);
            wordcopy[index] = '\0';
            letternum++;
        }
    }
}

void readhighscoretable(struct highscore table[])
{

    FILE* fp;
    int numofwords;
    char name[20];

    fp = fopen("highscoretable.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("You cannot check the table before adding the proper file.");
        return false;
    }

    while (fscanf(fp, "%s %d", name, &numofwords) != EOF) {
        printf("%s\t\t\t%d\n", name, numofwords);
    }

     do { printf("0\t\t\t0\n");
        } while (strlen(table) >= 10);
    
    fclose(fp);
    return true;

}

void inserthighscoretable(struct highscore table[], int numofwords)
{
    int i, j;
    char name[20];

    printf("Please enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);

    i = 0;
    while (table[i].numofwords > numofwords && i < 10) {
        i++;
    }

    if (i < 10) {
        // Push down all the rest of the entries
        for (j = 9; j > i; j--) {
            strcpy(table[j].name, table[j - 1].name);
            table[j].numofwords = table[j - 1].numofwords;
        }

        strcpy(table[i].name, name);
        table[i].numofwords = numofwords;
    }
}

void savehighscoretable(struct highscore table[])
{
    FILE* fp;
    int numofwords;
    char name[20];

    fp = fopen("highscoretable.txt", "w");

    fprintf(fp, "%s %d\n", name, numofwords);

    fclose(fp);
}

void printhighscoretable(struct highscore table[])
{
    int i;

    if (table[0].numofwords > 0) {
        printf("\nHighscore Table\n");
        printf("--------------------------\n");
    }

    i = 0;
    while (table[i].numofwords > 0 && i < 10) {
        printf("%-3d%-20s%3d\n", i + 1, table[i].name, table[i].numofwords);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    char wordlist[849][20];

    int numofwords = 0;

    int targetwordindex;

    char guess[20];

    int numofguesses;

    struct highscore table[10];

    if (!readwordlist(wordlist)) {
        return 0;
    }

    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("Welcome to the word building game!\n");
    printf("----------------------------------\n\n");

    printf("In this game, you have to build a secret word using the letters given to you!\n\n");
    printf("You have got three chances for each word. If you use up your chances,\nthe game will be over.\n\n");

    do {
        targetwordindex = rand() % 849;

        printf("Word %d - ", numofwords + 1);

        printshuffleword(wordlist[targetwordindex]);
        printf("\n\n");

        numofguesses = 0;
        do {
            if (numofguesses == 1) {
                printf("Hint: the word starts with '%c'.\n",
                       wordlist[targetwordindex][0]);
            }
            else if (numofguesses == 2) {
                printf("Hint: the word ends with '%c'.\n",
                       wordlist[targetwordindex][strlen(wordlist[targetwordindex]) - 1]);
            }

            printf("Please enter your guess: ");
            scanf("%s", guess);

            numofguesses++;

        } while (strcmp(wordlist[targetwordindex], guess) != 0 && numofguesses < 3);

        if (strcmp(wordlist[targetwordindex], guess) == 0) {
            numofwords++;
        }

        printf("\n");
    } while (strcmp(wordlist[targetwordindex], guess) == 0);

    printf("Game over! You have guessed %d word(s) correctly.\n\n", numofwords);

    readhighscoretable(table);

    if (numofwords > 0 && numofwords >= table[9].numofwords) {
        inserthighscoretable(table, numofwords);

        savehighscoretable(table);
    }

    printhighscoretable(table);
}
```

It is likely that the problems happened within the function of savehighscoretable and readhighscoretable. If I deleted these two parts and then run the whole program, the game can at least be played properly. Once two of them can be coded properly, a high score table with first 10 best record will be shown and it can be constantly changed if the better game result is created during the game.

Here is the error messages:

c4700 uninitialized local variable used 'numofwords'

Comment: Can you guide us, and be more precise what part is not working as expected? Which function you try to write and is now problematic? Are there compile errors or runtime, or unexpected behavior?

Comment: @user3184950 I have added the difficulties and problems in my focused parts. Please feel free to look at them again if you have the time.

Comment: `fscanf` stops at spaces or any delimiter. I recommend using a binary format with variable length highscore struct for names. With unicode, characters can take up to 4 bytes, so not even 5 chinese characters will fit into your `name` buffer.

Comment: regarding: `fscanf(fp, "%s", word);`  the array `word[]` is only 20 bytes long.   the specifier: `%s` will no stop after 19 characters input (note: this specifier always appends a NUL byte ) so it will be very easy to overflow the input buffer: `word[]`  The result of the overflow is undefined behavior.

Comment: OT: regarding statements like: `printf("You cannot check the table before adding the proper file.");`  error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  Also, if the error indication came from a  C library function then should also output to `stdout` the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.   The function: `perror()` is made for this purpose.

Comment: regarding; `scanf("%s", name);`  1) it allows the user to overflow the `name[]` buffer.  2) should always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  Suggest: `if( scanf("%19s", name) != 1 ) { // handle error }`

Answer (score 0):

the posted code contains several problems.

Problems that your compiler should have told you about.

You need to correct all these problems.

here is the list of problems:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled1.c" -o "untitled1.o" 

untitled1.c: In function ‘printshuffleword’:

untitled1.c:49:22: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
   49 |     while (letternum < strlen(word)) {
      |                      ^

untitled1.c:51:24: warning: conversion to ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
   51 |         index = rand() % strlen(word);
      |                        ^

untitled1.c:51:17: warning: conversion from ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} to ‘int’ may change value [-Wconversion]
   51 |         index = rand() % strlen(word);
      |                 ^~~~

untitled1.c: In function ‘readhighscoretable’:
untitled1.c:71:16: warning: ‘return’ with a value, in function returning void [-Wreturn-type]
   71 |         return false;
      |                ^~~~~

untitled1.c:61:6: note: declared here
   61 | void readhighscoretable(struct highscore table[])
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
untitled1.c:79:25: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   79 |         } while (strlen(table) >= 10);
      |                         ^~~~~

      |                         |
      |                         struct highscore *
In file included from untitled1.c:4:
/usr/include/string.h:385:35: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘struct highscore *’
  385 | extern size_t strlen (const char *__s)
      |                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~

untitled1.c:82:12: warning: ‘return’ with a value, in function returning void [-Wreturn-type]
   82 |     return true;
      |            ^~~~

untitled1.c:61:6: note: declared here
   61 | void readhighscoretable(struct highscore table[])
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

untitled1.c: In function ‘savehighscoretable’:
untitled1.c:111:42: warning: unused parameter ‘table’ [-Wunused-parameter]
  111 | void savehighscoretable(struct highscore table[])
      |                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~

untitled1.c: In function ‘main’:

untitled1.c:159:11: warning: conversion from ‘time_t’ {aka ‘long int’} to ‘unsigned int’ may change value [-Wconversion]
  159 |     srand(time(NULL));
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~

untitled1.c: In function ‘savehighscoretable’:
untitled1.c:119:5: warning: ‘numofwords’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
  119 |     fprintf(fp, "%s %d\n", name, numofwords);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Compilation finished successfully.
```

Note: the statement: *Compilation finished successfully* only means the compiler applied some workaround to each of the problems, NOT that the correct executable was produced.

regarding your question:

```
untitled1.c:119:5: warning: ‘numofwords’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
  119 |     fprintf(fp, "%s %d\n", name, numofwords);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

in the function:

```
void savehighscoretable(struct highscore table[])
{
    FILE* fp;
    int numofwords;  // <-- not initialized
    char name[20];   // <-- not initialized

    // 1) fails to check that the call to `fopen()` was successful
    // 2) the mode `"w"` trims the file to zero contents
    //    perhaps you should use `"a"`
    fp = fopen("highscoretable.txt", "w");

    // writing the uninitialized values to a file
    fprintf(fp, "%s %d\n", name, numofwords);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I may be too new for this area. But I hope I can constantly make the progress!